# Javascript create dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary

If I have a dict like below:

```
const d = {"S1": [2, 3, 4], "S2": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

I want to create another dictionary that can get the len or the 1st element as value with the same key, like:

```
const n = {"S1": 3, "S2": 4} # len of the value array
```

I try to use a `map` like below:

```
Object.entries(d).map(([k, v]) => console.log(k, v))
```

It prints the key-value pair but how do I use that to create a new dictionary?

Comment: They're called "objects" in JavaScript. Dictionary is Python.

Comment: I think you have to explain more about your problem.

Comment: `const n = {"S1": 3, "S2": 4}` huh on 3 and 4.... unsure how you would get 3 and 4....

Comment: @LiaqatSaeed WHat more is needed? He has an object containing arrays, he wants an object with the corresponding array lengths.

Comment: @epascarello See the comment: "len of the value array". `[2, 3, 4].length == 3`

Comment: So `d.s1.length` is too hard so it needs a look up? reduce() is one solution.

Comment: @epascarello Come on, you know he wants something dynamic for an arbitrary object, you can't just hard-code keys like that.

Comment: @Barmar really??? Because no one heard of bracket notation? lol I just want to know what the real problem is. :)

Comment: `new Map(Object.entries(d).map(([key, arr]) => [key, arr.length]))` or `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d).map(([key, arr]) => [key, arr.length]))` or `Object.entries(d).reduce((acc, [key, arr]) => (acc[key] = arr.length, acc), {})`

Comment: @epascarello They don't know how to create the new object dynamically from the results of the map, e.g. `Object.fromEntries()`.

Comment: @Barmar btw is Object.entries+reduce faster than the Object.fromEntries+Objectentries+map. It looks so considering the first looks O(n^2)ish

Comment: @cmgchess I have no idea, I've never benchmarked them. I think they should both be O(n), though.

Comment: @Barmar oh yeah it chains so has to be O(n). my bad

Comment: The reduce version is probably much faster because it doesn't have to allocate all the intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have taken a good start in the right direction.
`Object.fromEntries` can be used to convert the key value pair array back to an object with the `Object.entries` + `map` you have started with

```js
const d = {"S1": [2, 3, 4], "S2": [5, 6, 7, 8]}

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(d).map(([k,v]) => [k,v.length]))

console.log(res)
```

as an alternative you could achieve the same thing with `Object.entries` + `reduce`

```js
const d = {"S1": [2, 3, 4], "S2": [5, 6, 7, 8]}

const res = Object.entries(d).reduce((acc,[k,v]) => ({...acc,[k]:v.length}),{})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

See inline comments:

```js
function mapLengths(obj) {
  // Convert entries back to object:
  return Object.fromEntries(
    // Convert "d" to entries (tuples) and map:
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      // Return a tuple with the key and value of the "length" property:
      ([k, v]) => [k, v?.length],
    ),
  );
}

const d = { "S1": [2, 3, 4], "S2": [5, 6, 7, 8] };
const n = mapLengths(d);
console.log(n); // { S1: 3, S2: 4 }

// If there is a value without a "length" property,
// the optional chaining operator will prevent an invalid access exception
// and just return "undefined":

const d2 = {
  "S0": null,
  "S1": [2, 3, 4],
  "S2": [5, 6, 7, 8],
  "S3": {},
  "S4": "hello world",
};

const n2 = mapLengths(d2);
console.log(n2); // { S0: undefined, S1: 3, S2: 4, S3: undefined, S4: 11 }
```